# How to implement a cluster graph in java

Tags: java, graph, charts, cluster-analysis

I want to draw a cluster graph like [this](http://www.langlor.com/index.php?/experiment/facebook-network-cluster/). Is there a library for this? How should I  build the data structure to contain the input data? Like a dictionary with key as the node itself and value as an array with the nodes connecting to. What could be a more precise term to describe this?

Comment: The link is no longer available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a library like [JUNG](http://jung.sourceforge.net/).

**JUNG** is a framework made for displaying and working with any kind of **graphs** and **networks** on Java. It supports transitions, collapsing, complex layouts, …

---

<sub>**About the data structure:** It is complicated, and depends on the type 
of cluster (bidirectional or unidirectional).

In the last case, you shouldn't use a `Dictionary`, 
or connections would be stored twice.

Look at JUNG, for example. I think its data is Serializable.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [JGraphT](http://www.jgrapht.org/): it provides the data structures and you can then render that using JGraph.

Comment: @jmendeth, can you please explain the reason more?

Comment: Sorry, I meant: because you want to draw a cluster map, and JGraphT doesn't have much control over data representation & layout on screen, I wouldn't use it here.